# Cannot use T4 templates inside a .NET Core project

Tags: c#, t4, .net-core

I have a .NET Core class library project and I want to use design-time T4 templates.

The tempalate compiles correctly, but when I try to use Reflection it raises an error

```
Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating91FD7CCD92D7361F64265F0C5C220E81E842FC4A778C4D459155BDB3A79CCB52D465743E28886D98FF13456BEB0A44361D5237CFADD6B4BDEEED323B315D2F62.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()
```

This is my code:

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" hostspecific="false" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration)\netstandard1.6\MyProject.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>

<#@ import namespace="MyProject" #>

using System;
using System.Reflection;
namespace MyProject
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void Method()
        {
            <#
                var type = typeof(Product);
                var properties = type.GetRuntimeProperties();
                // use properties here...

            #>
        }   
    }
}
```

I have added references to System.Runtime 4.1 using Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is not the usage of `System.Reflection`, but your reference to the library `MyProject.dll`.

The T4 template engine is not able to reference libraries targeting the .NET Platform Standard. To reference your library, you need to add a target for the .NET Framework (e.g. `net451` for .NET Framework 4.5.1) in the `project.json` of the referenced library.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {},
    "netstandard1.6": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
```

Then change the reference in your template to the added target framework.

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration)\netstandard1.6\MyProject.dll" #>
```

becomes

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration)\net451\MyProject.dll" #>
```