# How to deploy a Nuget package that provides a Powershell command like EF's Scaffold-DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core, nuget

Assume I am writing an automation script that generate files for .NET project <del>(since T4 is no longer supported in .NET Core projects)</del>. Now I want to deploy it using Nuget, so I can use commands similar to Entity Framework's `Scaffold-DbContext`. The project I wrote using Console App but I can easily transfer it to other type if needed.

I tried looking at the source code of Entity Framework and see that they are packing a [`init.ps1`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Tools/tools/init.ps1) file in order to add the commands and the implementation is in [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/e467e09b599fbc249852e387667c023f798e66a1/src/EFCore.Tools/tools/EntityFrameworkCore.psm1).

Sorry but this is as far as I can go. Is there any documentation on how to do this? Or if possible, please tell me on my case, how do I invoke my .NET Core project if I want to run this command?

`Scaffold-ViewModels -Input Models\Entities -Output Models\ViewModels`

**EDIT:** After further investigation, I see that EF is packing with the compiled binaries in their folder:

```
  <files>
    <file src="lib\**\*" target="lib/" />
    <file src="tools\**\*" target="tools/"/>
    <file src="$targetDir$*.psd1" target="tools/"/>
    <file src="../ef/bin/$configuration$/net461/ef.exe" target="tools/net461/any/" />
```

And their script is executing `ef.exe` with additional parameters. My question is: Any documentation on it? What are the parameters? (Like in their script, they include `$env` etc).

If possible, a tutorial/getting started on a Hello World for creating an automation script from Nuget would be appreciated.

Comment: "since T4 is no longer supported in .NET Core projects" ? Are you sure? Right now everithing is OK. Just set CustomTool to TextTemplatingFileGenerator

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij wow, didn't know that. Thanks. Still, I prefer using a compiled program/script if possible. Roslyn is much better.

Comment: Regarding T4 in .NET Core, maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879572/cannot-use-t4-templates-inside-a-net-core-project) helps? If not, please explain why you think T4 isn't supported in .NET core.

Comment: @Matt sorry, it was a problem with my VS I think. Previously, when I create a `tt` file, it didn't precompiled into `cs` file. @Roman pointed out that I can manually set `CustomTool` property to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` and it works.

Comment: @LukeVo - That makes sense, I once had a similar issue (not .NET core, normal .NET with EF) and had to change the **CustomTool** property as well. For some reason, the original value disappeared, changing it back helped in my case too. I suggest you change the question to "... T4 seems to be no longer supported ..." to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Matt thanks, I forgot about that. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to implement this use case:

*"On nuget package install I want to start a ps script that parse project sources and crate new genereated files"?*

You can't emulate TT script delivery this way because TT is the thing that is already installed as [VS extension](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox) (and is integrated to VS).

TT script delivery through NUGET was simple because on install it was required just to put tt file to the project folder.

For advanced scenarios you would need a custom `dotnet` tooling command 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility
or VS Extension or both.

Comment: Well, at first my intention was for replacing T4, but not necessarily. I want a general use case in which I can perform some arbitrary action using Powershell script, like what EF is doing. Checking your link on Extensibility. Looks promising.

Comment: But EF is integrated to VS dialog system. I'm not sure that MS do it on "nuget install level" - this should be proved (at least t4 templates for ASP generation from EF6 model  where located somewhere in VS2015 catalogs). And even if they do it with nuget install - that this is the correct way for independent developers. T4 and CLI extensions looks like shortest ways to publicate your codegeneration ideas. What is true - analyzing code with Roslyn is more flexible than referncing compiled libs to tt template. But you can combine T4 and Roslyn.

Comment: I am still checking on the Extensibility tools, sorry didn't have much free time to check it during the week. Btw, you should also add the info that T4 is still working in .NET Core projects. Previously I don't know why when creating a `tt` file in VS, it didn't set the `CustomTool` to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` so I thought it didn't work. I just had a VS update and now a `tt` file works well.

Comment: find a time to write a small essay about using dotnet extensibility for code generation. I also need to write codegeneration tool using Roslyn. do you have any ideas how we can join our efforts?

Comment: I have uploaded the tool here: https://github.com/BibliTech/Roslyn.ViewModels . I will write a gist soon once the Nuget package is published.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I worked with it, (which was a few years back) the `init.ps1` file was just a powershell script that runs inside visual studio inside your project context when you install the package. I assume that EF is complicated enough that it needs the binaries, but you can use all the regular powershell cmdlets to manipulate the project:

Think `New-Item` , `Copy-Item`, `Get-ChildItem`, `Test-Path`, `Add-Content`etc.

Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/?view=powershell-6 for more commands.